# How to load images dynamically in react using a Collage component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

Seems like all the examples are static when it comes to loading images. Though this code works it does not seem to render the divider <div> tag as the results (images) are displayed but stacked in to the first item of the Collage. The component I am using is react-multi-carousel which uses divider tag to separate the items to render.

```
<Carousel responsive={responsive}>
         <ul>
                {images.map(image => {    
                    return <div><img key={image} src={image}/></div>;
                  })}
          </ul>
  
</Carousel>;
```

This must be a simple fix but I can't seem to find the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to add the div tag. However, the Carousel doesn't seem to know i want two items. But there is now a space between the images using this:  **```      {images.map(image => {    
                    return ([
                    <div>,
                    <img key={image} src={image}/>,
                    </div>]);
                  })}```**

Answer (score 0):

Well i copied your code and did some changes.My Code renders the `<div>` tag.

```
const [images, setimages] = useState([
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513151233558-d860c5398176?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80",
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg"
  ]);
  console.log(images);

  return (
    <>
      {images.map((image) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <img key={image} src={image} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: This does indeed add a <div> tag but the Carousel still doesn't see the tag .. `<Carousel responsive={responsive}>
    <div>Item1</div>  
    <div>Item2</div>
</Carousel>`   <----- this works